# Not able to designate a Dormitory as Protective Custody

Tags: prison-architect

I recently acquired two Ex Law Enforcement prisoners, and I want to keep them from getting shanked. I created a larger cell with many amenities, which should take care of most of their needs except food. I have several officers deployed in the canteen, so I feel they are generally safe, but have not yet put them on permanent lockdown (as it feels more like a punishment than PC) so I'm trying to figure out how to do this. I assigned both PC inmates to this larger cell, but when trying to deploy it as a Protective Custody cell, the dormitory (the only way to have them share a cell) won't highlight on it's own. (See screenshots)

Screenshots:

This is the dormitory image in the regular screen (the showering inmate is also a PC inmate)
[image: Dormitory Image]

And here is the deployment screen, you can see that the dormitory is not selectable by itself without getting the hallway
[image: deployment screen]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For anyone who might care to see the fate of unfortunate Mr. Miller (pictured in yellow above), [this](https://twitter.com/timsebring/status/735727794756325377) tweet sums it up. He just couldn't stay away from danger. (I admit some policy changes *may* have contributed to his condition.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When designating restrictions on cells and dormitories, the area includes the room directly outside and any cells connected to that. This is a cell block- it's usually a good thing since you don't want to have to designate all those cells individually.

The easiest solution is to add a second wall and door in front of the dormitory, like an airlock. The airlock will count as the corridor and you will be able to assign it to protected prisoners without covering the whole room.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Ironically enough, shortly after this there was another Snitch/Ex-cop in the midst that I didn't identify, and his murder in the shower caused a riot where another one of my PC folks got killed. I guess such is prison life.. thanks for the solution!

Comment: Small Update: Even though they had a working shower in their cell, they still kept going to the general population shower, so I ended up having to put them on permanent lockdown.

Comment: @TimS. - if the "general population" shower is not designated for a particular prisoner group then anyone can, and will, use it; including the protected custody prisoners. As soon as you start using protected I find you have to designate everything else for particular groups.

Comment: @Tony I didn't realize that, but it explains a lot.. thanks for the tip.

Comment: @TimS. - Although it might also be possible to separate protected from the general population with a staff only corridor. Trouble is you then have to build all the facilities the protective custody prisoners will need: canteen, visitation, yard, etc. etc. You end up with a mini prison-in-prison situation :)

Comment: That's what I figured -- but that's what PC is after all I guess.